# VBA to copy solidworks files to a central folder

Tags: vba, object, solidworks, fso

Good morning, a coworker of mine asked me to take a look at his VBA for Solidworks and I'm stumped as to what the issue is. Basically, he is searching through old solidworks drawings to find ones relevant to a new project he is working on. If he finds one that is relevant, he uses a macro to make a copy of that drawing, move it to the folder for the new project, close the old file, and open the new one. The macro is as following

```
Sub Move_Copy()

Set swApp = Application.SldWorks
Set swModel = swApp.ActiveDoc
Set FSO = VBA.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Where the Copy Files are going
DestinationFolder = "\\SERVER\FOLDER\subfolder"

'Gets full path name of current file that is open
MyPath = swModel.GetPathName

'Gets File Name with extension
CurrentOpenFile = Mid(swModel.GetPathName, InStrRev(swModel.GetPathName, "\") + 1)
'This copies the file and moves it
Call FSO.CopyFile(MyPath, DestinationFolder & CurrentOpenFile, True)

'This Closes the Current Document
swApp.QuitDoc CurrentOpenFile

'This opens the moved file
swApp.OpenDoc6 DestinationFolder & CurrentOpenFile, swDocDRAWING, swOpenDocOptions_Silent, "", ERRORS, WARNINGS

End Sub
```

The line that is bugging for him is

```
Call FSO.CopyFile(MyPath, DestinationFolder & CurrentOpenFile, True)
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: What does "bugging for him" ***mean***? Does it throw an error? If so, what is the error?

Comment: He said it occasionally gives an error, but can't recall exactly what it is and isn't sure what changes sometimes cause it.. Yes I realize that's not the most helpful, our apologies.

Answer (score 0):

`bFailIfExists` if the last parameter of `CopyFile`.

> If this parameter is TRUE and the new file specified by lpNewFileName
>   already exists, the function fails. If this parameter is FALSE and the
>   new file already exists, the function overwrites the existing file and
>   succeeds.

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-copyfile)

That's a possibility. Also, check if `DestinationFolder & CurrentOpenFile` is valid.